# Can't read base64 HTTP POST in PHP

Tags: python, php, post, base64

I'm trying to send HTML content (page) via HTTP POST, using base64 encoding through Python code.

On the receiving side, I'm not getting the info.

This is the screenshot of the sent packet:
[image]

This is the php page that I'm using to read the received POST (I also tried using $_POST):

```php
<?php
echo "This is the request:<br>";
echo var_dump($_REQUEST) . "<br>";
?>
```

And this is the screenshot of the response packet:
[image]

Any idea what's wrong with my code or settings (either sender or receiver side)?

When I used Content Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded on the sender side instead of text/plain;base64, the POST parameters were identified, but after decoding the base64 content, I found it full of special characters.

Comment: Can you check the memory limit in php.ini?

Comment: Files data will be in `$_FILES`, not in `$_REQUEST`

Comment: This is not a file. It's an html

Comment: The problem is not with the limit, but with the content type. If I use application/x-www-form-urlencoded, I can read it in php, but when I decode the base64 content, I get special characters all over the place